# Bootstrap 3 datepicker inline beforeShowDay issues

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have made an inline datepicker, i only got 1 issue.
I can't implement the beforeShowDay option

i use PHP to load an array out of a database. I implement this with AJAX

code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var ajax = $.ajax({
   url : "dates.php",
   data : "action=showdates",
   dataType : "json"
});
ajax.complete(function(calendarEvents) {
   $("#inline").datepicker({
      beforeShowDay : ShowDay()
   });
   function ShowDay(date) {
      console.log('function showday');
      for (var i = 0; i < calendarEvents.length; i++) {
         var jaar = calendarEvents[i].slice(0,4);
         console.log(jaar);
      }
      console.log('showday');
    }
  });
});
```

the trouble i have atm is that i want to have appointment on certain days.
i would ike to use the `return [true, "classname", ""]` for dates with an appointment, and `return [true, "", ""]` for all the other dates. i hope i can get some help!

This is what i am trying to do: http://www.emirplicanic.com/javascript/jquery-ui-highlight-multiple-dates-in-jquery-datepicker

the problem is that my datepicker is inline so i cant directly implement into the `beforeShowDay: function(date) {
}`

Pls post a demo on jsfiddle or something like that, it would be appreciated =D

*btw i tried to give `beforeShowDay: ShowDay` but this doesn't call the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright i fixed it it was really easy XD, i had and old version of bootstrap datepicker. This version didnt support BeforeShowDay! I now got a newer version and it all works!